# How to change two font sizes within one table data?

Tags: html, replit

I want to have two different font sizes within one block. How can I make "The Falcon Family" size 20pt and "The Falcon fam is from..." size 15pt and still be one table data.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <table border= "20" borderColor = "#71a14d" bgcolor= "#d1e83f">
     <td colspan="7" style="font-size:20pt"> The Falcon Family</br>
     The Falcon fam is from Russia they are nomads traveling through out the world.</td>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

just wrap the second part in a span and add style

```html
  <table border= "20" borderColor = "#71a14d" bgcolor= "#d1e83f">
  <tr>
     <td colspan="7" style="font-size:20pt"> The Falcon Family<br>
     <span style="font-size:15pt"> The Falcon fam is from Russia they are nomads traveling through out the world.</span></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do like this.

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <table border= "20" borderColor = "#71a14d" bgcolor= "#d1e83f">
     <td colspan="7" style="font-size:20pt"> The Falcon Family
        <div style="font-size: 15pt;">The Falcon fam is from Russia they are nomads traveling through out the world.</div></td>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```